# How to send the whole catalogue of files to DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a catalogue of files (small ones, text files) some of the files are located in a subdirectory some of them at root directory.

So that is something like that:

```
c:\data\file.txt, 
C:\data\file2.txt, 
C:\data\2021\file1.txt
etc..
```

I would like to upload them - using a stored procedure - to a table like this:

```
[Id] - 1,
[File name] - c:\data\file.txt, 
[File content] - lorem ipsum
```

Of course, the database server and the files are on the same machine.

Is that possible with pure T-SQL code?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky 2019 with most of updates

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

If needed you can switch **FileContent** column to the `VARBINARY(MAX)` data type.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.targetTable;

CREATE TABLE dbo.targetTable (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FullyQualifiedFileName NVARCHAR(255),
    FileContent NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @directory NVARCHAR(255) = N'e:\Temp\Catalog\';

-- Step #1
-- Load file names from a directory into the targetTable
INSERT INTO dbo.targetTable (FullyQualifiedFileName)
SELECT FullyQualifiedFileName = @directory + file_or_directory_name
   --, level, is_directory, creation_time, size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem(@directory, N'*.txt');

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.targetTable;

--Step #2
-- Loop through the targetTable table and load files content
DECLARE @ID INT
    , @FullyQualifiedFileName NVARCHAR(255)
    , @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    , @RowCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.targetTable);

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN
   SELECT @FullyQualifiedFileName = FullyQualifiedFileName, @ID = ID
   FROM dbo.targetTable 
   ORDER BY ID DESC OFFSET @RowCount - 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
   
   -- do whatever needed, apply any logic, call stored procedures, etc.
   SET @sql = FORMATMESSAGE('UPDATE dbo.targetTable
        SET FileContent = (
        SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N''%s'', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x)
        WHERE ID = %i', @FullyQualifiedFileName, @ID);
    --PRINT @sql;
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

   SET @RowCount -= 1;
END

-- test
SELECT * FROM targetTable;
```